# ARtoolkit load a video files captured from 4k Camera Sony

Tags: c++, camera, mp4, calibration, artoolkit

I want to know that how to load a prerecorded video files(.MP4) captured from 4k camera by using ARtoolkit.

I need that to calibrate my camera and detect the markers.

I cannot get any information from their websites official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Their page on reading Video files is [here](http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=2_Configuration:config_video_capture).
Looks like it depends on your platform, but if on a mac you can use "any valid movie resource that QuickTime can open, including files and streams." using -movie=file:///path/to/file .  You'll likely have to [Set Environment var](http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=1_Getting_Started:general_environment_variables) ***ARTOOLKIT5_VCONF*** to configure your capture, or use the ***–vconf*** flag.

Comment: I am using the Ubuntu 16.04. Could you give me the whole command line to run .calibrate if my file is called tesd.MP4? like ./calibrate "-vconf = -moive = file://"

Comment: My command is this./calib_camera --vconf "-device=QUICKTIME -movie=/Users/shixianwen/Downloads/HDcarmeravideo/HDV_0137.MP4"
but it told me:CHESSBOARD_CORNER_NUM_X = 7
CHESSBOARD_CORNER_NUM_Y = 5
CHESSBOARD_PATTERN_WIDTH = 30.000000
CALIB_IMAGE_NUM = 10
Video parameter: -device=QUICKTIME -movie=/Users/shixianwen/Downloads/HDcarmeravideo/HDV_0137.MP4
Using supplied video config "-device=QUICKTIME -movie=/Users/shixianwen/Downloads/HDcarmeravideo/HDV_0137.MP4".
ar2VideoOpen: Error: device "QUICKTIME" not supported on this build/architecture/system.

Comment: Sorry not sure, depends on platform and mines different to yours.  Quicktime would be mac only, you'll have to find what formats your system supports that ARToolkit also supports.  Under "Capture Sources and Switching Them" on the docs you can see what Linux feeds are available.  Looks like GSTREAMER might be applicable to you?